# Show numeric keyboard on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

In FMX Delphi app, after I click on a button and open an InputBox, how can I show a numeric keyboard only (not alphanumeric)?

```
InputBox('Input Box', 'Prompt', 'Default string');
```

Comment: In property `KeybordType` select e.g. `NumberPad`

Comment: @TomBrunberg  Is it possible set property to InputBox('Input Box', 'Prompt', 'Default string');   On button click I open above inputBox need only numeric keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original question and thought you referred to an edit control with `inputbox`. It seems the `InputBox()` doesn't provide any means to define the keyboard to use.

Comment: `InputBox()` is for string input, not numeric input.  So no, there is no way to make it display the numeric keyboard. You will have to create your own dialog if you want that.